# Solve log4net deadlock

Tags: c#, multithreading, log4net

server code

```
public class RemoteSink : MarshalByRefObject, RemotingAppender.IRemoteLoggingSink
{
    public void LogEvents(LoggingEvent[] events)
    {
        foreach (var loggingEvent in events)
        {
            LoggingEventData logData = loggingEvent.GetLoggingEventData();
            logData.Message = "[" + logData.Domain + "] " + logData.Message;
            log4net.LogManager.GetRepository().Log(new LoggingEvent(logData));
        }
    }
}

private static void SetRemoteLoggingServer()
{
    TcpChannel channel = new TcpChannel(15642);
    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
    RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(new WellKnownServiceTypeEntry(typeof(RemoteSink), "LoggingSinkInConsoleDaemon", WellKnownObjectMode.SingleCall));
}
```

and server has a `RollingFileAppender`

```
RollingFileAppender rollingFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender();
rollingFileAppender.DatePattern = @"yyyy-MM-dd.lo\g.\tx\t";
rollingFileAppender.RollingStyle = log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Date;
rollingFileAppender.AppendToFile = true;
rollingFileAppender.File = logPath;
rollingFileAppender.Threshold = Level.All;
rollingFileAppender.StaticLogFileName = false;
rollingFileAppender.Layout = new PatternLayout(@"%date [t:%thread] %-5level ConsoleDaemon - %message%newline");
rollingFileAppender.MaxSizeRollBackups = 5;
rollingFileAppender.LockingModel = new FileAppender.MinimalLock();
rollingFileAppender.ActivateOptions();

BasicConfigurator.Configure(rollingFileAppender);
```

so the server also can `log.Info("xxxxx")`

client use remote appender to server

> server's RemoteSink::LogEvents runs in a work thread, and server log
>   something in mainthread, and i find sometimes it stuck, i attched and
>   VC shows it stuck at
>   log4net.dll!log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton.DoAppend(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent
>   loggingEvent = {log4net.Core.LoggingEvent}) + 0x52 bytes,  maybe where
>   is the source line "lock(this)"

i search internet, everyone says `log4net` is threadsafe, where am i wrong?

===============================solved============================================
i'm misleading by call stack which make me think about `log4net`'s error

i also used a `RichTextBoxAppender`([RichTextBoxAppender using log4net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484822/richtextboxappender-using-log4net/18840111#18840111)) in my server

the `RichTextBoxAppender` use `Invoke`, it should use `BeginInvoke` to make thread-safe

Comment: Enable unmanaged debugging and post the *complete* stack trace.

Comment: Old thread but RollingLogFileAppender is thread safe, is the Remoting appender only the static members are thread safe, not the instance members
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RemotingAppender.html

Comment: I have the same issue, logs from multiple threads are locked in DoAppend.