# Log information in text.file in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am creating a `Windows Form` application.

I created a log file which is saved in the following path: "Application/bin/debux/log.txt".

1. How can I read this file from the bin folder in a `RichTextBox`?
2. When I published this application, I saw the folder "Application Files" after installation.
   Is it possible to put my log.txt there?

Comment: 1. Read the file and set the content of your control to it. 2. You can put it anywhere you want unless you lack privilegies to access the folder from code.

Comment: Have you searched for resources on how to read a text file in c#? This is a common task are there are many resources online that would help you. Are you facing a specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use http://logging.apache.org/log4net/ (Apache log4net) for logging and write a custom appender in order to write into the RichTextBox. You even can copy & paste the code from [RichTextBoxAppender using log4net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484822/richtextboxappender-using-log4net).

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
RIRichTextBox.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory+"log.txt");
```